# Receiving subscription data on Meteor using slava:redis-livedata

Tags: meteor, redis

I am using Slava's redis-livedata package with Meteor: https://atmospherejs.com/slava/redis-livedata

I would like to subscribe to a particular match stored as a hash in Redis. In my methods file I am able to successfully insert, update, and delete hashes. In my publications file I am able to console log the specific hash if I use the hgetall method on the Redis collection and input the key. If I use the suggested matches method in the Slava package, it seems to return a cursor

```js
// publications.js
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { redisCollection } from '../collections.js';

Meteor.publish("get.match.redis", function (matchId) {
    if (!this.userId) { return this.ready(); }
    if (matchId) {
        return redisCollection.matching(matchId);
    } else {
        return this.ready();
    }
});
```

On the client side:

```js
// matches.js
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Tracker } from 'meteor/tracker';
import { FlowRouter } from 'meteor/ostrio:flow-router-extra';
import { redisCollection } from '../../api/collections';
import './matches.html';

Template.matches.onCreated(function () {
    const instance = Template.instance();
    this.matcher = new ReactiveVar();
    this.reload = new ReactiveVar(FlowRouter.getParam('id'));
    Tracker.autorun(() => {
        if (instance.reload.get() != "") {
            var matchId = "match_" + instance.reload.get();
            Meteor.subscribe('get.match.redis', matchId);
            let matchData = redisCollection.matching(matchId);
            console.log(matchData);
            var match = { ...matchData, _id: matchId };
            if(match){
                instance.matcher.set(match);
            }           
        }
    });
});
```

The above outputs the following to browser console:

```
Miniredis.Cursor {redisStore: M…s.RedisStore, pattern: undefined}
pattern
: 
undefined
redisStore
: 
Miniredis.RedisStore
name
: 
"redis"
observes
: 
[]
paused
: 
false
_keyDependencies
: 
{}
_kv
: 
IdMap {_map: Map(0), _idStringify: ƒ, _idParse: ƒ}
_patternDependencies
: 
{}
_savedOriginals
: 
null
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
count
: 
ƒ ()
fetch
: 
ƒ ()
observe
: 
ƒ (callbacks)
observeChanges
: 
ƒ (callbacks)
_getCollectionName
: 
ƒ ()
constructor
: 
ƒ (redisStore, pattern)
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

If I switch to hgetall in the client method:

```js
Tracker.autorun(() => {
        if (instance.reload.get() != "") {
            var matchId = "match_" + instance.reload.get();
            Meteor.subscribe('get.match.redis', matchId);
            let matchData = redisCollection.hgetall(matchId);
            console.log(matchData);
            var match = { ...matchData, _id: matchId };
            if(match){
                instance.matcher.set(match);
            }           
        }
    });
```

Then I receive the following error:

```log
Error: Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
    at throwIncorrectKindOfValueError (slava_miniredis.js?hash=e96c4ded917a0a76869dc382eb43b0dafb327e6f:201:5)
    at Miniredis.RedisStore.<computed> [as hgetall] (slava_miniredis.js?hash=e96c4ded917a0a76869dc382eb43b0dafb327e6f:1138:14)
    at Meteor.RedisCollection.<computed> [as hgetall] (slava_redis-livedata.js?hash=0423d610d8e1718d91a50009c3ce14e0f243a1f9:705:39)
    at matches.js:35:36
    at tracker.js:302:40
    at Tracker.withComputation (tracker.js:609:12)
    at Computation._compute (tracker.js:301:15)
    at Computation._recompute (tracker.js:318:16)
    at Tracker._runFlush (tracker.js:489:14)
    at onGlobalMessage (meteor.js?hash=7dd187e6c4c7dc8731ddaf9d1d993d3c3ba5a732:578:23)
```

I have tried several different ways to retrieve this data within a subscription, but I cannot seem to find the correct pub sub methods. I am able to retrieve the hash using Redis-cli and verified the type is hash. Please provide any guidance as available